# Передача параметра в хранимую процедуру в oracle из asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, c#

Здравствуйте!
Суть проблемы - есть некая строка, а именно - *“Sometimes,' said Pooh, 'the smallest things take up the most room in your heart.”*, если вставить ее в поле в бд через oracle sql developer - она вставляется корректно, если через приложение на asp.net, то вот такой результат: *¿Sometimes,' said Pooh, 'the smallest things take up the most room in your heart.¿*

Наставьте на путь истинный. Спасибо.

Тип поля в БД - **NVARCHAR2**

Хранимая процедура в пакете:

**I_Comment - интересующее нас поле**

```
PROCEDURE INSERTNEWSFLASH
(
i_StartTime DATE,
i_EndTime DATE,
i_Comment NVARCHAR2,
i_Priority NUMBER,
i_Type NUMBER,
i_AirlineCode VARCHAR2,
o_NewsFlashId out NEWSFLASH.NEWSFLASHID%type
);
```

Хранимая процедура в теле пакета:

```
PROCEDURE INSERTNEWSFLASH
(
i_StartTime DATE,
i_EndTime DATE,
i_Comment NVARCHAR2,
i_Priority NUMBER,
i_Type NUMBER,
i_AirlineCode VARCHAR2,
o_NewsFlashId out NEWSFLASH.NEWSFLASHID%type
) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT NEWSFLASHID_SEQ.nextval into o_NewsFlashId from dual;
  INSERT INTO NEWSFLASH
  (
    NEWSFLASHID,
    VALIDFROMDATE,
    VALIDTODATE,
    NEWSFLASHTEXT,
    NEWSFLASHPRIORITY,
    NEWSFLASHTYPE,
    AIRLINECODE
  )
  values
  (
    o_NewsFlashId,
    i_StartTime,
    i_EndTime,
    i_Comment,
    i_Priority,
    i_Type,
    i_AirlineCode
  );
END INSERTNEWSFLASH;
```

Нужная строка в коде

**dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Priority", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32, newsFlash.Priority);**

И код из c#:

```
public int Add(NewsFlashModel newsFlash)
    {
        using (IDataHelper dataHelper = dataHelperFactory.GetDataHelper(StaffTravelSettings.ConnectionStrings.ITravelDatabase))
        {
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_StartTime", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Date, newsFlash.ValidFromDate);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_EndTime", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Date, newsFlash.ValidToDate);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Comment", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String, newsFlash.NewsText);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Priority", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32, newsFlash.Priority);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_Type", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.Int32, (int) newsFlash.Type);
            dataHelper.AddParameter("i_AirlineCode", ParameterDirection.Input, DbType.String, newsFlash.AirlineCompanyCode);
            IDataParameter parameter = dataHelper.AddParameter("o_NewsFlashId", ParameterDirection.Output, DbType.Int32);
            dataHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("NEWSFLASH.INSERTNEWSFLASH");
            return Convert.ToInt32(parameter.Value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OracleType.NVarChar